# How to fetch console date on webpage react axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, fastapi

How to fetch api data on web page using axios in react js,

Expected :

Via GET api call i get some response in console , now  i want to print that console data in the web page

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
// import { data } from 'jquery'
class PostForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            key: '',

            
        }
        console.log(this.state)
    }

    changeHandler = e => {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
    }

    submitHandler = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        
        axios
        .get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/hvals_hash?key=${this.state.key}`)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    }

    render() {
        const { key } = this.state
        
        return (
            <center><div>
                <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
                    <div>
                        <h2> DATE PICKER</h2><br></br>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            name="key"
                            value={key}
                            onChange={this.changeHandler}
                        />
                        
                    </div>
                    <br></br>
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div></center>
        )
    }
}

export default PostForm
```

NOTES :

data in the console like Array data (24)

["["/home/fraction/FastAPI/videos/video1.mp4", "/home/fraction/FastAPI/videos/video2.mp4", "/home/fraction/FastAPI/videos/video3.mp4", "/home/fraction/FastAPI/videos/video4.mp4", "/home/fraction/FastAPI/videos/video5.mp4"]

Comment: Store response on some state?

Comment: is the answer helpful to you?

Comment: @novonimo Hello sir, did you got any answers

Comment: Hello sir @Raghav , I need more explanation about the problem as I couldn't understand the core issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store your api response in some state

- take a state maybe name myVideoUrl
- setState this with your response from api
- then you need to import video player here so this component become parent and your video player component will be a child then pass this state myVideoUrl to your child component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
// import { data } from 'jquery'
class PostForm extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        key: '',
        myVideoUrl: ''
    }
    console.log(this.state)
}

changeHandler = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
}

submitHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault()

    axios
        .get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/hvals_hash?key=${this.state.key}`)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            this.setState({ myVideoUrl: response })
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
}
render() {
    const { key } = this.state

    return (
        <center><div>
            <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
                <div>
                    <h2> DATE PICKER</h2><br></br>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name="key"
                        value={key}
                        onChange={this.changeHandler}
                    />

                </div>
                <br></br>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        //im assuming your child component here
            <MyVideoPlayer url={this.state.myVideoUrl} />
        </div></center>
    )
}}
export default PostForm
```

after this you can access this.props.url in your child component

Comment: can you please help to fetch resonse data as VideoURL's